# Kubespray on offline(or on-premise) environment

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I'm new to k8s and kubespray.

My purpose is to build k8s cluster in on-premise env.
With EC2s which have public IPs and internet access, everything was fine.
But with more complicated constrains, I'm stuck. Below is my constraint.

- 1 bastion which has public IP and internet access
- n nodes which don't have both public IP and internet access

According to [kubespray document](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/docs/offline-environment.md), it requires somewhat many settings.
But my opinion is, since bastion has full internet access, there can be an easy way to build k8s cluster with kubespray.

Is there any blogs or step by steps to do this?

Comment: Since you linked to the relevant document, what other kind of "step by step" are you looking for? Actually, let me put it another way: what have you tried, and what error is it producing for you?

Comment: Hi @mdaniel, actually I dont' have any error now. The reason why I'm asking this question is that I don't understand this document fully. I'm not familiar with building proxyserevr / docker registry / ubuntu repo. I want to find helpful posts for beginners...

Comment: Then installing kubernetes is going to be the source of an overwhelming number of S.F. questions, as it is _for sure_ not hand-holdy either. This question needs more focus. Start with the first item in your list that you don't understand, read up on it, try **something**, and ask specific questions about the errors you encounter. Right now, it reads like "write me a tutorial" which is not the purpose of this site. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel Thanks for your advice. I understand that constructring on-premise k8s cluster is not a simple thing. As you said, I have to start one by one. If I have concrete error, I will ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, if your bastion can access the public registries and repositories, then you can install some Squid server, proxying queries on behalf of your Kubernetes nodes.

In which case, this is no longer a disconnected  deployment, and we may set the `http_proxy` `https_proxy` and `no_proxy` variables in `group_vars/all.yml`, using that proxy pulling assets out of their original place.

Try with something like `apt-get install squid` or `dnf install squid`. A basic squid.conf might look like the following:

```
http_port 3128
cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
cache_mem 256 MB
cache_dir aufs /var/spool/squid 10240 16 256
maximum_object_size 1024 MB
cache_effective_group proxy
hosts_file /etc/hosts
logfile_rotate 4
logformat combined %>a %ui %un [%tl] "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" %Hs %<st "%{Referer}>h" "%{User-Agent}>h" %Ss:%Sh
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log combined
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
error_directory /usr/share/squid/errors/en
http_access allow all
http_reply_access allow all
cache allow all
icp_access allow all
```

Test connectivity, from one of your Kubernetes nodes:

```
# curl -vvv --proxy http://10.42.44.100:3128/ https://perdu.com
...
* Connected to 10.42.44.100 (10.42.44.100) port 3128 (#0)
...
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to perdu.com:443
...
```

Now, make sure your Kubespray inventory does set proper variables using that proxy. Container Runtime and OS package manager configuration would both use those.

---

If setting up that proxy is not suitable for some reason, then you will need to mirror all the images and files mentioned in that `offline-environment.md` doc.

Maybe setup an Nginx server for the kubectl / etcd / ... binaries and files, and run a docker-registry container, mirroring those images. Though bear in mind that your container runtime should be properly configured ignoring insecure registry errors (additional Kubespray variables to set), or your OS should trust the CA that signed your registry server certificate.

Comment: Thanks @SYN. I will search with the keyword `squid` server!